# Updating keys of dictionary with a list of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dictionary

```
d={'key1':value1,'key2':value2}
```

Desired output is

```
d={u'key1':value1,u'key2':uvalue2}
```

Now I have created an empty list dic where I'm extracting all the key values and modifying it with unicode, now the keys in the dictionary `d` need to be updated with the values in the list.

There are multiple dictionaries like this and all of it is again coming under a list.

What need to be modified in the code for the desired output

```
dic=[]
for a in dict_lst:
    for x in a:
        print x
        dic.append(unicode(x))
```

Comment: is `value1`/`value2` strings?

Comment: value 1 is string and value2 may be string or a number

Comment: You mention dict and then list, exactly what do you have? You need to provide better example.

Comment: l=[{'key1':value1,'key2':value2},{'key4':value4,'key5':value5} output is l=[{u'key1':uvalue1,u'key2':value2},{u'key4':value4,u'key5':uvalue5}]

Comment: what is tht? you cannot have `d=` inside a list, do you have a list of dictionaries? Also you say you have strings and number, do you want to change the numbers into unicode?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use another blank dict for this -

```
d={'key1':'value11', 'key2':'value2'}

d2 = {}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d2[unicode(k)] = unicode(v)
print d2
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your certain values following no rule.

```
k_ = 'key1', 'key5' # values to unicode by their key
dic = map(lambda d: {unicode(k): unicode(v)
           if k in k_ else v for k, v in d.iteritems()}, dict_lst)
```